# how to find the shortcode [Wordpress] file location

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My wordpress post contain a custom shortcode.

I want to edit the code, but can't find the file where the code is available.

Is there any function to find the code.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could do a search in files using your code editor. I use sublime text 3 and can do 'find in files' and pass it the shortcode name. It pulls up all the matches it finds in the files.

What code editor are you using?

And we could maybe find it manually, what is the shortcode called? Its might be in a plugin or theme.

Comment: notepad++ , is there any way to find using wordpress API or trick to do that

Comment: There must be a trick like that somewhere in the ether, but not that I've heard of! Notepad++ has a find in files feature. If you can search all the files on your site you can pass it the shortcode text and see what comes up.

Comment: You could ask at [WordPress Development](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). Someone there is more likely to find a way to do it the way you want.